# Adding plugin for a custom protocol into Wireshark

Tags: qt, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

Using Qt, I developed a Wireshark plugin for decoding some data manually in a window. I also downloaded the Wireshark code for implementing it in Qt.

How can I add my protocol (plugin) name into the protocol field, so that if I click it, my plugin loads dynamically and becomes visible? Which part of the Wireshark code should be modified?

Answer (score 2):

You can start by checking the path where Wireshark plugins are located. **Run Wireshark, then select Help → About Wireshark → Plugins.** Here you can check where the default Wireshark plugins are located in your computer.

I built a Wireshark plugin for version 1.12.0. After building with Ubuntu Wireshark sources, I got a file with the plugin, named `plugin_name.so`. I copied this `plugin_name.so` into the folder with Wireshark plugins:

```
sudo cp plugins/plugin_name/.libs/plugin_name.so /usr/local/lib/wireshark/plugins/1.12.0/
```

**On Windows it should be a `.dll` file instead of a `.so` file.**

To check that the `plugin_name` plugin is loaded, I ran Wireshark again, selected Help → About Wireshark → Plugins and there I saw `plugin_name` and the other plugins that Wireshark loaded.